# how to split the textarea into parts in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open the 5 urls inputted by the user in the `textarea`
But the array is not taking the url separately instead taking them altogether:

```
function loadUrls() 

{

    var myurl=new Array();

    for(var i=0;i<5;i++)

    {

        myurl[i] = document.getElementById("urls").value.split('\n');

        window.open(myurl[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use 5 different input fields? You can't guarantee the `textarea` contents will be formatted the way you expect

Comment: I agree here, what is your reasoning for the one large text area?

Answer (score 0):

You only should need to split the text contents once. Then iterate over each item in that array. I think what you want is:

```
function loadUrls() {

    var myurls = document.getElementById("urls").value.split('\n');

    for(var i=0; i<myurls.length; i++) {
         window.open(myurls[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('urls');
var button = document.getElementById('open');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var urls = input.value.split('\n');
  urls.forEach(function(url){
    window.open(url);
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="open">Open URLs</button>
<textarea id="urls"></textarea>
```

Note that nowadays browsers take extra steps to block popups. Look into developer console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues I see with this.

1. You are declaring a new `Array` and then adding values by iterating through 5 times. What happens if they put in more than 5? Or less?
2. `split` returns a list already of the split items. So if you have a String: this is a test, and split it by spaces it will return: [this, is, a, test]. There for you don't need to split the items and manually add them to a new list.

I would suggest doing something like:

```
var myUrls = document.getElementById("urls").value.split('\n');

for (var i = 0; i < myUrls.length; i++) {
     window.open(myUrls[i]);
}
```

However, as others suggested, why not just use multiple `inputs` instead of a text area? It would be easier to work with and probably be more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

### Basically:

```
document.getElementById("urls").value.split('\n');
```

returns an array with each line from textarea. To get the first line you must declare [0] after split the function because it will return the first item in `Array`, as `split` will be returning an `Array` with each line from *textarea*.

```
document.getElementById("urls").value.split('\n')[0];
```

Your function could simplify to:

```
function loadUrls(){
    var MyURL = document.getElementById("urls").value.split('\n');//The lines
    for(var i=0, Length = MyURL.length; Length > i; i++)
        //Loop from 0 to length of URLs
        window.open(
            MyURL[i]//Open URL in array by current loop position (i)
        )
}
```

### Example:

```
line_1...
line_2...
```

... To:

```
["line_1","line_2"]
```